# what am i doing wrong when starting up Autogen Studio?

Tags: autogen

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in *run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in *run_code
File "C:\Users\Genregod\anaconda3\envs\ag\Scripts\autogenstudio.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
File "C:\Users\Genregod\anaconda3\envs\ag\Lib\site-packages\autogenstudio_*init**.py", line 1, in 
from .chatmanager import *
File "C:\Users\Genregod\anaconda3\envs\ag\Lib\site-packages\autogenstudio\chatmanager.py", line 9, in 
from .workflowmanager import AutoGenWorkFlowManager
File "C:\Users\Genregod\anaconda3\envs\ag\Lib\site-packages\autogenstudio\workflowmanager.py", line 12, in 
class AutoGenWorkFlowManager:
File "C:\Users\Genregod\anaconda3\envs\ag\Lib\site-packages\autogenstudio\workflowmanager.py", line 50, in AutoGenWorkFlowManager
def process_message(self, sender: autogen.Agent, receiver: autogen.Agent, message: Dict, request_reply: bool = False, silent: bool = False, sender_type: str = "agent") -> None:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'autogen' has no attribute 'Agent'

Tried debugging , reviewed the code lines in the Traceback and even ran it through AI. Looked at the autogen folder but I'm not sure it's referencing that one.